# Simple scope exercise

Tags: javascript

```
function a() {  
    var a = 1;  
    console.log(a);  
    var b = function() {  
        console.log(a);  
        var c = function() {  
            console.log(a);  
        }  
    }  
}  
a();  
b();  
c();
```

Tried calling all 3 functions this also doesn't work, it says b is not defined;

Comment: Because `b` and `c` are not called - only declared in their respective inner scope.

Comment: You defined three functions, but you only called one of them (`a`).  For you to log all three times you would need `b()` and `c()` as well.

Comment: It's an `exercise` for Stack Overflow Community? This **Q&A** site, not **exercise-solution** one.

Answer (score 0):

its not defined because you are missing the point of scope. `b` as a function is only available inside of `a`. `c` as a function is only available inside of `b`. 
For example, the following code would be fine.

```
function a() {  
  var a = 1;  
    console.log(a);  
    var b = function() {  
      console.log(a);  
      var c = function() {  
          console.log(a);  
      }  
      c(); // c is available because we are inside the function b
    }  
    b(); // b is available because we are inside the function a
  }
a();
```

You should probably do some reading around scope if you dont understand this as is a very basic a pivotal device in javascript.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful!